# Creating a versioning table, holds the present version and the old version

Tags: oracle, create-table

How can i create a table that has the old and present version of the table. 
I am trying to do it by creating a table base on the old and present version, then adding columns that states where it came from and if its active or not, here is my attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE DVersioning (
  Version VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT 'V1',
  Active number (1,0) DEFAULT '0'
) as (SELECT * FROM details );
```

But I produce this error:

> may not specify column datatypes in this CREATE TABLE

Then i will just insert the new version with different version and active.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you use CREATE AS SELECT syntax do not specify columns datatypes, its iherited from SELECT clause.

Comment: Have you thought about using Flashback Data Archive?

Comment: we are not allowed to use other than sql developer

Answer (score 0):

haha find a way CREATE TABLE DVersioning
AS SELECT 
* FROM
(
SELECT 
    T1.adsh,
    T1.name,
    'V1' Version,
    'N' Active
FROM details T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    T2.adsh,
    T2.name,
    'V2' Version,
    'Y' Active
FROM detailsv2 T2
);